# Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e09'

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I am having to modify an old web project that us using classic asp. There are actually 2 different projects that are clones of each other, they just point to different databases.

I modified the code from the first project (asp, db, stored procs etc.) and it all works great.

I then copied all that code to the other project since they are clones. All works just fine there too. I can execute the stored procs in query analyzer and all the data comes back as expected and it shows up on the display asp pages.

When i hit the edit button on the page I get the **"Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e09'"** and it shows the select part of the query in the error window.

I dont get anything about permissions etc.. If I view the page source the data is actually in there. I am really confused as to what is going on.

Anyone have any suggestions or things to look for.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a permissions error based on the usual meanings of this error code.

I would manually log in to the database using the same credentials you have configured in your application's connection string. Then run the same query and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for that - removed the link as that site is now dead.